# css ul li :hoover want to change background color. But see part of previous background color or li expands

Tags: css

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/x9ghnf99/7/

Have ul li menu

```
<div class="nav" id="nav1">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Set initial background color for `li`. Also set some padding from text (`a`) to "borders" of `li`. And also want to create rounded corners

```
#nav1 ul li {
display: inline;
background-color: #dddddd;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

On hoover want to change/replace color, for example to green, so as green fills whole `li`

With this http://jsfiddle.net/psxvy320/

```
#nav1 ul li  :hover{
background-color: green;
}
```

green is only around text (`a`) and for other part of `li` i see previous background.

Tried http://jsfiddle.net/psxvy320/1/

```
#nav1 ul li  :hover{
background-color: green;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;    
}
```

See part of previous background and `li` expands to left and right.

I want to see `li` the same widht/height, want only to change background, like here http://jsfiddle.net/psxvy320/4/ (below menu)

What need to change/add to the code?

Comment: instead nav1 ul li  :hover - to nav1 ul li:hover http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ngqhgg00/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space between `li` and `:hover` in your code. 
It should be `.nav ul li:hover`. When you add a space `li :hover`, it adds the hover effect to the child element (in this case, to the `<a>`)

Fiddle1: http://jsfiddle.net/psxvy320/5/
Fiddle2: http://jsfiddle.net/x9ghnf99/10/

Answer (score 1):

Add the padding for `a` instead of `li` so that the whole item will be clickable.  and change `li` display to `inline-block`

```
#nav1 ul li a{

 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
 display: block;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/x9ghnf99/11/